# Checking if a value exists in JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

Learning JSX here and I was wondering if theres a way to check if a value appears in a object in JavaScript

i.e
*We have an obj*:
anObj ={
myFoo : "MONDAY;TUESDAY;WEDNESDAY"
}

How could I check if monday etc appears in this object?

Comment: can you specify if you know at which level of nesting you want to look for it ?

Comment: This is neither a React or JSX issue. Just use JS to check to see if `anObj.myFoo` [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) 'MONDAY'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the value in Object.values with .includes()

```
let valueExists = Object.values(obj).includes("value you looking for");
```